# Is it possible to add While Loops to Microsoft Project Workflows

Tags: project-server

I'm a beginner at Sharepoint Developing and I was given a task to modify the out of the box Project Server 2010 workflow (SampleProposal2) from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15511).

Is it possible to add while loops to Project Server Workflows? I dealt with while loops only in a Sequential Workflow for Sharepoint.